# Apply CIFilter to UIImagePickerController feed

Tags: ios, avfoundation, core-image

Anyone found a way to apply a CIFilter on a live UIImagePickerController camera feed?

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't.

Also, this is a duplicate question.

See: [Filter Live camera feed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11257991/filter-live-camera-feed)